# Showing the count (in render) only if it is greater than 0 after the data is loaded inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the `useEffect`, `notifications` are fetched from the database:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.loading != true) {
         props.fetchNotifications(currentUserId, submissionId)
    }
}, [])
```

Somewhere in the return statement I have the following code to apply a filter on the notification list and check if the length of the remaining list is bigger than zero. Then, if it is, I use the same filter statement to calculate the count to display this time. But, I am doing the computation two times, creating redundant code. I wonder in React if there is a solution this is issue.

```
   props.notifications &&
   <div className="col-sm-4">
       <div className="mb-3">
           <h5 className="text-primary bg-light pl-1 pt-2 pb-2">
               <i className="fa fa-bell-o"></i> &nbsp;Notifications
               <span className="badge badge-pill badge-primary small ml-2">
                   {
                       Object.keys(props.notifications)
                           .filter(function (id) {
                               return props.notifications[id].isDiscussionType == false &&
                                   props.notifications[id].isRead == false 
                           }).length > 0 &&
                       <span>{
                           Object.keys(props.notifications)
                               .filter(function (id) {
                                   return props.notifications[id].isDiscussionType == false &&
                                       props.notifications[id].isRead == false 
                               }).length} new
                       </span>
                   }
               </span>
           </h5>
           <NotificationList isDiscussionType={false} />
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the results in a constant to only perform the `filter` operation once:

```
const notificationsLength = props.notifications ? Object.keys(props.notifications).filter(function (id) {
    return props.notifications[id].isDiscussionType == false &&
        props.notifications[id].isRead == false
}).length : 0

return (
    <span className="badge badge-pill badge-primary small ml-2">
        {

            notificationsLength &&
            <span>{notificationsLength} new</span>
        }
    </span>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wonder if this would wait until `props.notifications` are loaded from the database.

Comment: You could check this in `notificationsLength` assignment. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can extract that out of return and create a variable, something like:

```
const filteredNotifications = Object.keys(props.notifications)
                                    .filter(id => props.notifications[id].isDiscussionType == false 
                                               && props.notifications[id].isRead == false })
```

Then you can do something like

```
<span className="badge badge-pill badge-primary small ml-2">
 {
  filteredNotifications.length > 0 &&
  (<span>{filteredNotifications.length} new </span>)
 }
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!